# PyQt5 - QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor for server respons content

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, httpresponse, qwebengineview, server-response

For developing my browser application, I have installed a `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor`, so I can filter the URLs being reuquested. I would like to now be able to have a similar thing but for the server response content ie a theoretical `QWebEngineServerResponseInterceptor` kind of class. I am unaware of any classes that exist, and I don't even know whether the `QtWebEngine` even supports intercepting server responses, as this may go directly to the `Chromium Networking Stack`, and therefore bypass the `QtWebEngine` completely. I'd like to be able to read and modify Javascipt, html, etc... before it is loaded into the `QWebEngineView`.

I was thinking of blocking all URLs in the `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor`, and then requesting them individually with a `QNetworkAccessManager`, however I think this is a bad idea because Qt switched to the `Chromium Networking Stack` for a reason and also whilst I could analyse the response with the `QNetworkReply`, I don't know how to load this into the `QWebEngineView`, or how to capture and load the `POST data` into the `POST` requests.

Is there some sort of workaround that I could use, in order to read and modify the server response content before it is loaded into the `QWebEngineView`?

Comment: Why don't you implement an external proxy that does that job?

Comment: I'd like to have all the intercepting done on the same device making the http requests, as the backend of the application will have a complex packet routing system, done via other devices.

Comment: okay, as I already pointed out in other posts: There is no such class, I recommend reading the Qt WebEngine docs (there are few classes) before asking.

Comment: Okay thanks, do you know if it safe to use the QtNetwork instead of the Chromium Networking Stack - by blocking all urls in a `QWebEngineRequestUrlInterceptor` and then requesting them manually through a `QNetworkAccessManager`?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: I have thought of a possible workaround solution; In the `interceptRequest` function of a `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor`, manually request the urls and store the reply (`QNetworkReply.readAll()`), and then redirect the original url request to the locally saved version, also allows for offline browsing to these sites.